# Program not stopping when I press "Stop"

Tags: python

I have a very strange problem. When I press stop, the code does not stop. see:

```py
import tkinter as tk
x=tk.Tk()
stops=False
def stop():
    stops=True
    print("STOPPED")
tk.Button(x,command=stop,text="Stop").pack()
while not stops:
    print(stops)
    x.update()
    x.update_idletasks()
```

If I press stop, why does still it keep on printing?
the `stops` variable is not edited in the while loop, so why doesn't it stop?
I have also tried adding this to the end of the while loop:

```
if stops:
    break
```

But it still does not stop. Why?

Comment: Because `stops` is a local variable in `stop`, ignoring the global one.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel So how do I fix it?

Comment: Did you try putting `global variable python` into a search engine?

Comment: @Max  Hey check out my answer

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.  Any tutorial on functions will point out the problem; any tutorial including "global" will teach you the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to globalise the variable "stops" to modify the variable.

```
def stop():
    global stops
    stops=True
    print("STOPPED")
```

Answer (score 0):

*I am bit late but with complete explanation*

#### Yes, using `global` keyword will solve this issue.

#### Why and How ?

Explanation:
Global variables are the one that are defined and declared outside a function and we need to use them inside a function

If you create a variable with the same name inside a function, this variable will be local, and can only be used inside the function. The global variable with the same name will remain as it was, global and with the original value.

Now if you want to update this global variable via function you need to use keyword `global` which will update the global variable(i.e, `stops`)

```
import tkinter as tk

x=tk.Tk()
stops=False


def stop():
    global stops
    stops=True
    print("STOPPED")


tk.Button(x, command=stop, text="Stop").pack()

while not stops:
    print(stops)
    x.update()
    x.update_idletasks()
```